# If else not working in cypress it only going into if condition in cypress

Tags: cypress

cy.get('body').then(($body)=>{

```
    if($body.find('.field-validation-error'))
    {
        //cy.contains('Invalid username or password.').should('be.visible')
        cy.log('Invalid username or password.')   
    }
     else if($body.find('#inspire > div.v-application--wrap > div:nth-child(1) > div.root-container.fill-height.fill-width > div.base-layout-main-content.box > div.row.content-wrapper.fill-width.fill-height > div.fill-height.body-right-wrapper.col-sm-12.col.col-xs-12.col-md-7.col-lg-8.col-xl-9 > div > div > div > div.px-4.col.col-12 > div > span')){

        cy.log('logged In')

     }
 })
```

It is not working like if else do ....it is not going in else part, if the if() condition falis it should go into the else part but it not executing else() condition

Answer (score 0):

`$body` is a jquery instance so it will always return an `object`.
[image]

You can check: `console.log(typeof $body.find('.field-validation-error'))`

use:

```
if ($body.find('.field-validation-error').length)
```